# Optics to image laser reflection on sensor

Tags: optics, lenses

I'm a software dev dabbling in laser optics and I'd like to use lenses to project a laser reflection onto a sensor strip. I know how this works in principle, but I have no idea what sort of lenses I should be using to get a projection that's as uniform in size as possible, and which software tools would work well for modelling the optical setup, if any.

[image]

Note that I am asking here for theoretical information, e.g. which formulae apply, which lens models should be used if applicatable, etc. There is a [seperate question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49944/) for nitty gritty engineering details like brands and such.

Comment: You don't really give a lot about the practical problem you want to have solved, in terms of laser power, wavelength etc. However, I fail to see why you need any optics at all before the detector? If your reflective side doesn't alter the spatial profile or phase of your beam, just aligning the beam along the normal to the detector should be fine. Generally here I'd use a prism to pick a reflection of the beam, and then use this on a CCD-camera to image the beam. Alsom, this question is wrong for this forum, as it is more practical and applied, and not physics general

Comment: Sure! It's an analog laser rangefinder. Related electronics question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609491/what-is-the-basic-circuit-to-wire-up-a-position-sensitive-detector-or-psd

I am looking for theoretical answers here to my practical problem so I can do a good job modelling it. There is a seperate engineering question for the nitty-gritty stuff: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49944/

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do with the optics.  What is the reflecting surface?  Is it a specular reflector (like a mirror) or diffuse (like a piece of paper)?   Is it flat?  Is its orientation and position fixed?  How large is it?  Why the line sensor and not just a single channel detector?  How does this operate as a range finder?

Comment: It is still not clear why you'd need a lens at all after the reflection ?

Comment: I don't know, I'm clueless! :) "No optics" is of course a great answer.